# Swift 5 UIButton with image causing my apps freezing after open url

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application that needs to open third-party apps (i.e Whatsapp), it runs smoothly when I build this app using Xcode 10, but in Xcode 12, it's causing the freeze. Does anyone have to face this problem before?

My code was like this

1. declaring button

```
let buttonWA: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        v.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_whatsapp"), for: .normal)
        return v
    }()
    
    let buttonEmail: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        v.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_email"), for: .normal)
        return v
    }()
```

Then I add some functions to be called each button

```
@objc func WaPressed() {
        let no = "*************".urlwithPercentEscapes()
        let urlWhatsApp = "whatsapp://send?phone=\(no)"
        self.openUrl(urlString: urlWhatsApp)
    }
    
    
    @objc func EmailPressed() {
        self.openUrl(urlString: "mailto:myEmail@gmail.com")
    }

func openUrl(urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

Everything running smoothly, and open third apps very well, but when I returning back to my apps, it goes freeze without telling me anything

I've tried change ".normal" options to other options like ".application" etc in the line

```
        v.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_whatsapp"), for: .normal)
```

and it makes my apps running well again, but I need this "for: .normal" state so bad.

Then I've tried to change

```
        v.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_whatsapp"), for: .normal)
```

to

```
v.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ic_whatsapp"), for: .normal)
```

and it works, but then the image scale is messy.

Could anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying other options, I figure it out with add RenderingMode when I set Image in my button, the code looks like this:

**For whatsapp button**

```
v.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_whatsapp").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
```

**For email button**

```
v.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_email").withRenderingMode(.automatic), for: .normal)
```

I don't understand why I can't set "automatic / alwaysOriginal" both. But this way works for me.

Thankyou